# Minimal CSS for Internet Explorer (7,8,9)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is the first time I will be implementing for IE9 and since I've installed Windows 7 which came with IE9, every site I have checked that we've built has some issues in IE9.

What I'd like to know is:

1. Is there a way to absolutely use minimal CSS to sort out all three browsers or will there always be the need for conditional css for the different IE versions?
2. Is there a specific doctype I should be using that will sort a lot of this out?

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on your needs and requirements.  My personal website has exactly one style sheet that works across all major webbrowsers.  But my personal website is very simple.
2. Nope.  But please, do pick and include a doctype.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) explains how it will effect rendering in IE.

Answer (score 0):

1) 8 and 9 are pretty similar, 7 has a few things missing. Yes, you will always have to take into account all 3. This may be by removing any problems with the browser BEFORE you style with a CSS reset, although this doesn't solve everything, or use conditionals.

2) Not really, the browser will automatically select one if one is not defined. Either way, it won't change how the page renders.

Comment: Thanks Jason! You said _"by removing any problems with the browser **BEFORE** you style with a CSS reset"_. How can I do this? My usual method of development is to add the reset before I do anything else, thinking that this would "null" all browsers so that a person can start developing on an even playing field. Are you saying there is a better way to do this? Thanks again.

Comment: No, that is essentially what most people do. It is the best way to achieve browser consistency.

Comment: The browser will go into quirks mode if you do not use a doctype and you never want to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to minimise the problems is to use an initial [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file to bring as many of the differences back into line as possible.

Also, consider using a well established CSS framework such as [960 Grid](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://960.gs/&ei=NXQxTt3QJMeHhQf-lrnuCg&usg=AFQjCNG7o9W1K2PN56W6QumHlshaE6Kq7g&sig2=sOekaHVBrxl1kvAuqLcRWA) or [Blueprint](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.blueprintcss.org/&ei=P3QxTuD_HoO7hAeo_83pCg&usg=AFQjCNH9oYZ92HoBQJf9TP9QVgbClsm2kQ&sig2=3n011NJkCc4HL50r5U9Xrw). This will at least mean you are adopting a well used / contributed to framework which will minimise the cross browser inconsistencies that you are unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS reset idea is a good one if you are just starting out but will hide differences between browsers that may confuse you later.

The best doctype to use now is `<!DOCTYPE html>` which puts all browsers into standards mode.